# Nuxt can't auto redirect with middleware (protected routes)

Tags: routes, nuxt.js

I'm trying to set up a automatic redirects from protected resources to login pages when the user is not authenticated.

When I implement the example redirect from nuxt I get his error:

```
Error: Redirected when going from "/" to "/login" via a navigation guard.
    at createRouterError (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2065:1)
    at createNavigationRedirectedError (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2024:1)
    at eval (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2376:1)
    at Vue._next (client.js?06a0:299:1)
    at app.context.redirect (utils.js?ebed:235:1)
    at eval (auth.js?14c2:8:1)
    at promisify (utils.js?ebed:314:1)
    at middlewareSeries (utils.js?ebed:291:1)
    at Vue.callMiddleware (client.js?06a0:264:1)
    at Vue._callee6$ (client.js?06a0:267:1)
```

It also seems to somewhat lock up the chrome browser.

Here's my implementation.

~/middleware/auth.js

```
export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
  if (process.client && !store.getters["isLoggedIn"]) return redirect("/login");
}
```

~/nuxt.config.js

```
export default {
  // ..
  middleware: ["auth"],
  // ..
};
```

~/src/pages/protected.vue

```
<script>
  export default {
    middleware: "auth",
  };
</script>
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, you don't need to specify the middleware in individual pages if you add it in nuxt.config.js

Comment: @UdithIshara - I believe you're right.  I've tested it a number of different ways.  It WILL work when removing the middle ware from `nuxt.config.js` and placing the middleware in individual pages.  It will NOT work with the middle ware inside of `nuxt.config.js` whatsoever.  So, I believe the implementation is INTENDED to work as your suggesting.  Its just not.

Answer (score 0):

It may just be unclear to me based on the code you've shared, but the middleware defined within `nuxt.config.js` needs to be a child of the `router` object. So:

```js
export default {
  // ... 
  router: {
    middleware: ["auth"],
  }
  // ...
}
```

Also may be worth mentioning, if you have the [standard auth module](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/) included in your project, it uses the same middleware implementation with the same name, so you may want to be careful using "auth" as your filename here.